# ¿Cómo utilizar el OR?

Tags: java, android-studio

Hace poco empecé a utilizar Java para crear aplicaciones con Android Studio.
Lo que estoy intentando es manejar el OR para evaluar dos opciones de resultado ya que la respuesta es "b" o "B" ambas respuestas son correctas solo que una es minuscula y la otra Mayuscula.

Esto es el código:

```
public class Act_Esp extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText txt1;
EditText txt2;
EditText txt3;
EditText txt4;
EditText txt5;
EditText txt6;
EditText txt7;
EditText txt8;
EditText txt9;
EditText txt10;
EditText txt11;
EditText txt12;
EditText txt13;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_act__esp);
}

public void Res1 (View view){
txt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
String result1 = "b";
    if (txt1.getText().toString().equals(result1)){ //Es igual.
    Toast.makeText(this, "Correcto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} else if (!txt1.getText().toString().equals(result1)){ //Es diferente.
    Toast.makeText(this, "Vuelve a intentarlo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

Comment: En vez de `equals` podrías utilizar `equalsIgnoreCase` ya que este permite hacer validaciones omitiendo si están en mayúsculas o minúsculas.

Comment: Gracias Kevin Delva me ha funcionado

Comment: @KevinDelva agregalo como respuesta por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias formas para realizar esto si las dos opciones son correctas ya sea "b" o "B".

Una puede ser "normalizar" usando `toLowerCase()` para convertir el texto del `EditText` en minúsculas, y de esta forma compararlo con "b" que es en minúsculas.

```
public void Res1 (View view){
    txt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    String result1 = "b";
    if (txt1.getText().toString().toLowerCase().equals(result1)){ //Es igual.
        Toast.makeText(this, "Correcto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (!txt1.getText().toString().equals(result1)){ //Es diferente.
        Toast.makeText(this, "Vuelve a intentarlo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

> **[toLowerCase()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase--)** : Convierte todos los caracteres de esta cadena en
>   minúsculas utilizando las reglas de la configuración regional
>   predeterminada.

---

Otra opción es usar el método `equalsIgnoreCase()` el cual realiza la comparación no importando si el texto o carácter esta escrito en mayúsculas o minúsculas.

```
public void Res1 (View view){
    txt1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    String result1 = "b";
    if (txt1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(result1)){ //Es igual.
        Toast.makeText(this, "Correcto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else if (!txt1.getText().toString().equals(result1)){ //Es diferente.
        Toast.makeText(this, "Vuelve a intentarlo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

> **[equalsIgnoreCase()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase-java.lang.String-)** : Compara esta Cadena con otra Cadena, ignorando las consideraciones del caso.

Comment: Gracias por los datos @Jorgesys, ahora veo dos formas de evaluar la respuesta